# Keep moving controls lower on the page as the grid view above grows in height

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` in a panel, and then I have another panel below this one with some controls in it. Let's call the two panels `pnlGrid` and `pnlLower`. The html is like so:

```
    <asp:Panel id = "pnlGrid">
    <!-- Grid View here -->
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel id = "pnlLower">
    <!-- Other controls here -->
</asp:Panel>
```

As rows are added to the grid, the height of the grid keeps increasing. If still rows are added after the height of the grid reaches initially set height, the grid gets taller and its new rows are displayed over (or under, on the z-axis) `pnlLower` and its controls.

I want that as the grid grows in height, the panel below, i.e. `pnlLower` (and all other panels below it) should keep moving lower to make room for the grid indefinitely. I do not want to set a maximum height for the grid.

How do I do that?

Comment: How is the `initially set height` of the grid set? If you're setting a `height` somewhere, use `max-height` instead. If you're not deliberately setting a `height`, find out what is and kill it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the height of your panel and add a CSS property to make a vertical scroll. For this you can use the `overflow` property. It's values are as follows: `visible` | `hidden` | `scroll` | `auto`, and there are properties: `overflow-y` (vertical), `overflow-x` (horizontal) and just `overflow` (both).

In your css file, you could add a style like this:

```
    .scrollPanel {
       overflow-y: scroll;
       height: yourFixedHeightpx;
    }
```

and on your webform, something like:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlGrid" runat="server" CssClass="scrollPanel">
  <!-- Grid View here -->
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlLower" runat="server">
    <!-- Other controls here -->
</asp:Panel>
```